# Can not write x00 in hex c++

Tags: c++, serial-port

I need to write to serial port 0x00 for the device address but when i try, it is written nothing.

```
const char bufferTX[11] = "\xA5\x00\x05\x10\x00\x00\xD0\x01\x00\x00";
```

This is my buffer which i wanna sent to serial port. And below function is sending datas to serial port

```
for(int k = 0; k<sizeof(bufferTX); k++)
{
  RS232_cputs(cport_nr, &bufferTX[k]);  
  printf("sent: %c\n", bufferTX[k]);
}
```

Comment: You do know that just about *all* characters you write are unprintable? Printing them as characters would not be very productive.

Answer (score 1):

The name `RS232_cputs` (notice the final `s`) hints that it is intended for writing *strings*, which are NUL-terminated in C. Googling the function named brought me to [some documentation](http://doxygen.rcsmobility.com/namespacesynthese_a623bcce7f605cbef86ada07543b792c3.html) which seems to confirm this, citing the implementation as:

> ```
> while(*text != 0) RS232_SendByte(comport_number, *(text++));
> ```

You should probably use a byte-based function instead of a string-based one.

Comment: Did mean this as byte-based beacuse i also tried this but it didnt work {'\xA5','\x00','\x05','\x10','\x00','\x00','\xD0','\x01','\x00','\x00'}

Comment: @Sukru The data is fine, no need to change that. It's the *function* which interprets them differently than you likely want.